# How to use recyclerview-selection by setting the key as a string?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Using the android library `androidx.recyclerview.selection`, I have tried to implement multiple selection in `RecyclerView` following the tutorials [here](https://proandroiddev.com/a-guide-to-recyclerview-selection-3ed9f2381504) and [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-add-selection-support-to-a-recyclerview--cms-32175).

But, I want my `key` to be a `String`, instead of `Long`, but I am facing two errors as follows:

```
tracker = SelectionTracker.Builder<String>(
    "selection_id",
    recyclerView,
    StableIdKeyProvider(recyclerView),    // this line shows error
    MyItemDetailsLookup(recyclerView),
    StorageStrategy.createStringStorage()    // this line shows error
    ).withSelectionPredicate(
        SelectionPredicates.createSelectAnything()
    ).build()
```

I want some details about how is `ItemKeyProvider` implemented for a `String`, and secondly,

```
StorageStrategy.createStringStorage() // this shows error
StorageStrategy.createLongStorage()   // this doesn't show error
```

why is that happening, when everywhere I have replaced the generic type from `Long` to `String`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/selection/StorageStrategy), `StorageStrategy` is used for storing keys in saved state,

```
/* for    Long    keys */    StorageStrategy.createLongStorage()
/* for   String   keys */    StorageStrategy.createStringStorage()
/* for Parcelable keys */    StorageStrategy.createParcelableStorage(Class)
```

Also, according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/selection/StableIdKeyProvider.html), `StableIdKeyProvider` provides for keys of type `Long`. That is why, your `StorageStrategy` is showing error because it is expecting `Long` keys.

To provide `String` keys, you have to create your own `ItemKeyProvider` class. For more details on `ItemKeyProvider`, you can refer the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/selection/ItemKeyProvider) here.

This is how you can implement `ItemKeyProvider` class for `String` keys:

```
class MyItemKeyProvider(private val rvAdapter: MyAdapter): ItemKeyProvider<String>(SCOPE_CACHED) {
    override fun getKey(position: Int): String = rvAdapter.getItem(position).myKey
    override fun getPosition(key: String): Int = rvAdapter.getPosition(key)
}
```

and in `MyAdapter`:

```
class MyAdapter(private val myList: ArrayList<MyModel>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    // functions used in MyItemKeyProvider
    fun getItem(position: Int) = myList[position]
    fun getPosition(key: String) = myList.indexOfFirst { it.myKey == key }

    // other functions
}
```

where `MyModel` is something like this:

```
data class MyModel (
    val myKey: String,
    // other data
)
```

Now, you can simply build your `SelectionTracker` like this:

```
myTracker = SelectionTracker.Builder(
        "my_selection_id",
        recyclerView,
        MyItemKeyProvider(rvAdapter),
        MyItemDetailsLookup(recyclerView),
        StorageStrategy.createStringStorage()
    ).withSelectionPredicate(
        SelectionPredicates.createSelectAnything()
    ).build()
```

Note that you should not write the following code in your `Adapter` if you are not using `StableIdKeyProvider`:

```
init { setHasStableIds(true) }
```

otherwise it will show this error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference
```

This [tutorial](https://proandroiddev.com/a-guide-to-recyclerview-selection-3ed9f2381504) shows how to implement `recyclerview-selection` with `Long` keys, also showing how to implement your own `ItemKeyProvider` class for `Long` keys.

To implement `recyclerview-selection` with `Parcelable` keys, I have found a sample code [here](https://github.com/kgmyshin/recyclerview-selection-sample).